# How do mouse pointer events relate to onClick in a div?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently getting mouse and touch via pointerup, pointerdown, and I'm struggling with the different behavior of these two.

I didn't run into any issues when doing it with touch.
Touching a div to call a function, or touching and holding a div to perform the desired action, all worked fine.

However, there is a problem when doing so via mouse.

There's nothing wrong with calling a div's function via mouse click, but when the mouse is pressed and held, it performs the hold action differently than a touch, and also calls the div's function via the default click.

```
let touchTapTimer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;

const setSelectMode = (e: PointerEvent) => {
   // wanted Func
};

const handleScroll = () => {
   clearTimeout(touchTapTimer);
};

const handlePointerDown = (e: PointerEvent) => {
   touchTapTimer = setTimeout(() => setSelectMode(e), 800);
   window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
};

const handlePointerUp = (e) => {
   clearTimeout(touchTapTimer);
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll); 
};

divRef.addEventListener('pointerdown', handlePointerDown);
divRef.addEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp);

~

const selectItem = () => {
   // default Func
}

<div
   ref={noteRef}
   onClick={selectItem}
>
```

1. If set onClick on a div, it will be called both via touch and via mouse.
2. However, in the case of pointerDown -> setTimeout -> setSelectMode, touch does not call the div's onClick function, but mouse does.
3. I don't want the div's onClick function to be called when the mouse is held down, as it is with touch, and I want to know why touch and mouse behave differently in that situation.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're using React, not plain JS, in which case you shouldn't be using plain JS addEventListener but React's `onEventName` handlers. So not `divRef.addEventListener('pointerdown', handlePointerDown);`, but `<div ... onPointerDown={handlePointerDown} />`. Also, when adding a scroll listener, remember to use `{passive: true}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touch Events: When you touch and hold on a touchscreen device, it usually triggers a `touchstart` event, followed by a `touchend` event when you release. There's no inherent "click" event in touch devices unless the browser synthesizes one, which usually happens after a short tap, not a long press.

Mouse Events: Mouse events are more straightforward. A mousedown event occurs when the mouse button is pressed, and a mouseup event occurs when it's released. A click event is fired after the mouseup if the mousedown and mouseup occur on the same element quickly.

Browsers often synthesize click events for touch interfaces to ensure compatibility with sites designed for mouse interaction. This is why your onClick handler is getting called on a touch device after a tap.

You can use the event object to differentiate between a mouse and a touch event. The PointerEvent interface has a pointerType property that you can check to see if the event is triggered by a mouse, pen, or touch.

Modify your handlePointerDown function to check the pointerType. If it's a mouse, you can either prevent the default behavior or set a flag that you check in your onClick handler.

In your case, you might want something like this:

```
let isMouseHeldDown = false;

const handlePointerDown = (e: PointerEvent) => {
    if (e.pointerType === 'mouse') {
        isMouseHeldDown = true;
    }
    touchTapTimer = setTimeout(() => setSelectMode(e), 800);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
};

const handlePointerUp = (e) => {
    isMouseHeldDown = false;
    clearTimeout(touchTapTimer);
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
};

const selectItem = () => {
    if (!isMouseHeldDown) {
        // default Func
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I listened to what you said and went to https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/event-listener.html to test it out. When I shortened the touch, the browser synthesized a click event, but when I lengthened the touch, there was no click event. That's amazing, my question is solved, thank you!